# How can I split my Ethernet line into multiple?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

I'm trying to figure out what it is that I need and what best suits my needs. It's between a router and a switch.

So in the room that I need this in I currently only have 1 Ethernet port on the wall and currently my main computer is plugged into it. However, I have multiple computers that also need to be connected to the internet, and one of these computers is going to serve as a web server with a public IP.

I also don't want speed to be split between all devices. For example, I have 150mbp/s up and 50mbp/s down and I don't want (if I had 3 devices) to split that speed 3 ways. I need each device to use as much as it can, when it needs to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch), but make sure it supports [Gigabit Ethernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_Ethernet) (rather than just [Fast Ethernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Ethernet)) since your connection is faster than 100 Mbps.

You'll need an extra cable that goes from the wall into any port on the switch, and then you plug your other devices into any of the other ports on the switch.